# Insert non-breaking whitespace in Word textboxes

Tags: vba, excel, ms-word

#### Background (skip if needed, there to help people Googling the same problem)

When you create text boxes in word (I was using the auto caption on figures), use italicised text and align right, you often find a bit of the last letter can be cut off.

Here's the situation where I noticed it first (zoomed in alot)

[image: Normal]

Or to accentuate with a more flourishy script:

[image]

F is a good letter to recreate this problem with. [This is a known bug](http://www.wordbanter.com/showthread.php?t=3813), and the solution on that page was to add in a non-breaking whitespace (<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>space</kbd> or `chrW(160)` [in VBA](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_word-msoffice_custom/word-vba-insert-non-breaking-space-in-word-table/b58de59d-efcf-4765-99cd-bce1dff512e1))

#### Problem

I tried to create a macro to add a non breaking space to each textbox in my document, if:

- The textbox is right-aligned
- The text inside is italicised
- There isn't one already

Here's the code I came up with:

```
Sub captionSpaces() 'placed in normal.dot module
Dim grp As Shape
Dim tb As Shape
Dim txRng As Range
Dim str As String
For Each grp In ActiveDocument.Shapes 'all my textboxes are in groups - I might add handling in case they aren't
    For Each tb In grp.GroupItems 'Loop through all shapes in all groups
        If tb.Type = msoTextBox Then 'Single out text-boxes
            Set txRng = tb.TextFrame.TextRange 'Get text content
            If txRng.Italic And txRng.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = wdAlignParagraphRight Then 'only act on this sort of text
                str = txRng.Text
                If Right(str, 1) <> ChrW(160) Then 'check for a space already present
                    str = str & ChrW(160) 'create new string...
                    txRng.Text = str '...and set it (could have done in 1 step)
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Next tb
Next grp
End Sub
'NB I appreciate I could have put all my conditions in one IF with AND,
'but I find this clearer and I think it will be marginally quicker 
'since you aren't SETting the str over and over
```

This doesn't work for me and I am not familiar enough with Word VBA to work out why; in all but one of my captions it doesn't do anything, in one of them it seems to add 2 new lines. Very bizarre

Possible avenue; the groups are wrapped in 3 ways; Square, Tight and Top & Bottom, the captions are all beneath the images (and grouped to them). The one that gets the extra lines is the only one wrapped tight.